# Floating button in TabPanel

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm new in Sencha Touch and I'm trying to create a TabPanel with a button which is always shown in a corner of each Tab.

Currently I'm trying to create a floating button

```
    this.trashButton = new Ext.Button({
        iconCls: 'trash',
        iconMask: true,
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        ui: 'plain',
        floating:true,
        handler: this.trashButtonTap,
        scope: this
    });
```

And then show it

```
    this.on('activate', function() {
        this.trashButton.show();
    });
```

Button is shown correctly but as soon as I click anywhere it dissapears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after `hideOnMaskTap: false`